# Unique fields added to Wordpress Pages editor

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to customise the page editor in Wordpress so I have 5 text fields which I can pull out in the front end page. This is because the Wordpress manager is a bit hopeless with no HTML skills and the content of these boxes will populate buttons and a drop-down select. These fields will be completely unique to the page being edited. How do I go about this? Do I need to build my own plugin or customise an existing one or other?

Comment: Sounds like you want custom fields. There is documentation on this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields . If you don't wanna create these fields yourself Check out this plugin http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ lets you simple and fast create different custom fields such as WYSIWYG-editor/dropdown/radiobuttons etc.

Comment: This was indeed what I needed - for anyone else reading, you'll need to hit the screen options tab at the top, then you can start adding custom fields with no need for a plugin. Then just call these fields in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Custom Fields is a great plugin for this. You can target a particular page to display fields on and then output your fields in the front end templates using:

```
the_field('field_name');
```

See here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/